# OctoberCMS Rainlab.Builder- Error on "hasOne" relation to same model

Tags: laravel, orm, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm developing an October CMS Plugin for managing animals (with rainlab.builder). 
Animals have a couple of fields and relations. Every animal have a father and a mother animal. But when I try to safe my animal the following error appears:

Event Log:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
Column 'id' cannot be null in dir/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/
Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:413
```

Plugin animal form:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id'
cannot be null (SQL: update `prefix_animals_animal` set `id` =  where
`prefix_animals_animal`.`id` = 1 and `prefix_animals_animal`.`id` is 
not null)" on line 666 of dir/website/vendor/laravel/framework/
src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
```

The error only appers when I use the relations (child -> father, child -> mother).

---

### Code

I have implemented the following hasOne - relations to my **animal model**:

```
/* Relation */

public $hasOne = [
    'father' => [
        'Namespace\Animals\Models\Animal',
        'key' => 'id',
        'otherKey' => 'id'
    ],
    'mother' => [
        'Namespace\Animals\Models\Animal',
        'key' => 'id',
        'otherKey' => 'id'
    ]
];
```

This are my fields from **field.yaml**:

```
father:
    label: Father
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    nameFrom: name
    descriptionFrom: description
    emptyOption: 'No father'
    span: left
    type: relation
mother:
    label: Mother
    span: right
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    nameFrom: name
    descriptionFrom: description
    emptyOption: 'No mother'
    type: relation
```

I would be very happy if someone have a solution for these kind of relations. 
Cheerio!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `id` as the primary key for the relation as this is not good practice.

Actually this creates the problem you are seeing also. Currently your model is using the `id` for primary Id, mother Id and father Id. You can't do that.

Add `mother_id` and `father_id` to the Animal model and change the relation definition to this:

```
public $hasOne = [
    'father' => [
        'Namespace\Animals\Models\Animal',
        'key' => 'father_id',
        'otherKey' => 'id'
    ],
    'mother' => [
        'Namespace\Animals\Models\Animal',
        'key' => 'mother_id',
        'otherKey' => 'id'
    ]
];
```

PS. In your case you dont have to define `key` and `otherKey` as the default value for `otherKey` is "id" and the `otherKey` value is created from the relation name with the "_id" suffix.

Comment: Good morning dragontree. Thank your for your fast answer. I'll test this out when I'm back at home!

Comment: Thank your for your great answer! I forgot to add the two colums (father_id and mother_id) to my child model. With the new database keys and changes to the relation everything works.
I thought this works similar to the file attachments (without an extra column)...

Comment: AND: I changed the hasOne relation to "belongsTo" ralation.

public $belongsTo = [
    'father' => [
        'Namespace\Animals\Models\Animal',
        'key' => 'father_id'
    ],
    'mother' => [
        'Namespace\Animals\Models\Animal',
        'key' => 'mother_id'
    ]
];